# evisual basic console app framework Module

Tags: vb.net

I'm a new programmer having this error. If I need to make the program to find the magic number between to number how I can do it

> vbc : error BC30420: 'Sub Main' was not found

```
Imports System

Class GFG

  Public Shared Function isMagic(ByVal n As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim sum As Integer = 0

    While ((n > 0) _
                OrElse (sum > 9))
        If (n = 0) Then
            n = sum
            sum = 0
        End If

        sum = (sum _
                    + (n Mod 10))
10

    End While

    ' Return true if sum becomes 1.
    Return (sum = 1)
  End Function

  ' Driver code
  Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim n As Integer = 1234
    If GFG.isMagic(n) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Magic Number")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not a magic Number")
    End If

  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a VB.NET Console Application project, the IDE generates `Module1` containing a `Main` method for you. In the project properties, the startup object is set to that `Module1`, which means that it will look for a `Main` method in that module. If you expect it to start somewhere else then you need to specify that in the project properties, on the *Application* page. If you select a type then I believe that it will look for a `Main` method in that type and error if it doesn't find one. If you specify `Sub Main` then I believe that it will check all types for a `Main` method and error if it finds multiple.